# German style railway clock. Appalling use of SVG?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Don't laugh, my knowledge of SVG practically **zero**. This is my first attempt at animating svg shadows. All I wanted was to dynamically access the filter feOffset's dx and dy attributes to give the clock hands realistic shadow positions as they move around the dial.
The only way I could do it was to rip apart the svg and reassemble it with JavaScript. It works a treat and runs at about 1.5% to 4% cpu on my machine with a setTimeout cycle of about 30mls (needed for smooth second hand). I discarded requestanimationframe  because the time goes to pot with long periods without page focus.
As it stands, the script is creating/replacing (I think!) new svg on each new cycle.
Anyway, my question is there a better/proper way to access and manipulate dx and dy?
Ps: I'm only using svg because the shapes I want obviously can't be generated with css and as the clock is fully resizable, an image png etc is unacceptable.
Thanks for any help.

```js
(function () {

    /* German Station Style Clock */


    /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^ Config below ^^^^^^^^^^^^ */

    var clockSize = 500;
    var casecol = 'rgba(40,40,40,1.0)';
    var dialcol = 'rgba(255,255,255,1.0)';
    var numcol = 'rgba(40,40,40,1.0)';
    var seccol = 'rgba(200,0,0,1.0)';
    var handcol = 'rgba(40,40,40,1.0)';
    var shadowOpacity = 0.3;
    var shadowBlur = 0.2;
    var shadowAngle = 0.6;
    var clockShape = 50;
        /* (max) 50 = round  (min) 0 = square */
    var numoutline = 'no';
        /* 'yes' or 'no' */
    var numfill = 'rgba(255,0,0,1.0)';
    var numshad = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)';

    /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ End config ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */

    var d = document;
    var dgts = [];
    var e = 360/12;
    var degr = 0;
    var nums = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'];
    var tmr;
    var mls = 1000 / 30;
    var radi = Math.PI / 180;
    var offs = 60 * radi;
    var canstroke = ('webkitTextStroke' in d.body.style);
    var str = '-webkit-text-fill-color: '+numfill+';'
        +'-webkit-text-stroke-width: '+xy(0.4)+'px;'
        +'-webkit-text-stroke-color: '+numcol+';';
    var wks = (canstroke && numoutline == "yes")?str:'';
    var broff = (clockShape < 20)?2:0;
    var presec;
    var premin;
    var prehou;
    var rnd = 'id'+Math.random() * 1;
    var idx = d.getElementsByTagName('div').length;
    d.write('<div id = "'+rnd+'" style="display:inline-block;line-height:0px;"></div>');

    function xy (a) {
        return (a * clockSize / 100);
    }

    /* Clock dial */
    var dial = d.createElement('div');
    dial.setAttribute('style', 'display:inline-block;'
        +'position: relative;'
        +'height: '+clockSize+'px;'
        +'width: '+clockSize+'px;'
        +'background-color: '+dialcol+';'
        +'border: '+xy(2)+'px solid '+casecol+';'
        +'border-radius: '+clockShape+'%;');
    d.getElementById(rnd).appendChild(dial);

    /* Clock markers */
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        dgts[i] = d.createElement('div');
        dgts[i].setAttribute('style', 'display: block;'
            +'position: absolute;'
            +'width: '+xy(16)+'px;'
            +'height: '+xy(14)+'px;'
            +'margin: auto;top: 0;bottom: 0; left: 0;right: 0;'
            +'font: bold '+xy(13)+'px  Arial;'
            +'line-height: '+xy(13)+'px;'
            +'text-align: center !important;'
            +'color: '+numcol+';'+wks+';');
        dgts[i].innerHTML = nums[i];
        dial.appendChild(dgts[i]);
        degr += 30;
        dgts[i].style.top = xy(0) + xy(84) * Math.sin(-offs + e * i * radi) + 'px';
        dgts[i].style.left= xy(0) + xy(84) * Math.cos(-offs + e * i * radi) + 'px';
        dgts[i].style.transform = 'rotate(' + (degr) + 'deg)';
        dgts[i].style.transformOrigin = 'center center';
    }

    /* Generic container div for all hands */
    var handContainers = 'display: block;'
        +'position: absolute;'
        +'height: '+xy(100)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(20)+'px;'
        +'font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px; padding: 0;'
        +'margin: auto; top: 0;bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;'
        +'transform-origin: center center;'

    /* Hour hand */
    var houHand = d.createElement('div');
    houHand.setAttribute('style', handContainers + 'transition: .5s cubic-bezier(0.666, 1.91, 0.333, 0);');
    dial.appendChild(houHand);
    var houC = d.createElement('div');
    var housvg = '<polygon points="94,46 100,40 106,46 106,118 94,118" style="fill:'+handcol+'; stroke:none"/>';

    /* Minute hand */
    var minHand = d.createElement('div');
    minHand.setAttribute('style',handContainers + 'transition: .4s cubic-bezier(0.666, 1.91, 0.333, 0);');
    dial.appendChild(minHand);
    var minC = d.createElement('div');
    var minsvg = '<polygon points="95.5,11.5 100,7 104.5,11.5 104.5,122 95.5,122" style="fill:'+handcol+'; stroke:none"/>';

    /* Seconds hand */
    var secHand = d.createElement('div');
    secHand.setAttribute('style',handContainers);
    dial.appendChild(secHand);
    var secC = d.createElement('div');
    var secsvg = '<polygon points="98.8,11 100,9.8 101.2,11 101.6,42 98.4,42" style="fill:'+seccol+'; stroke:none"/>'+
    '<polygon points="98.1,58 101.9,58 102.5,122 97.5,122" style="fill:'+seccol+'; stroke:none"/>'+
    '<circle cx="100" cy="50" r="8.5" style="fill:none; stroke:'+seccol+'; stroke-width:6.5"/>';

    function dropShadow(s, h) {
        var depth = xy(h);
        var angle = s * radi - shadowAngle;
        var vsa = depth * Math.cos(angle);
        var hsa = depth * Math.sin(angle);
        return {vsa:vsa, hsa:hsa}
    }

    var str1 = '<svg height="'+xy(100)+'" width="'+xy(20)+'" viewBox="90.25 -4 20 200" ><defs>';
    var str3 = '<feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="'+shadowBlur+'"/>';
    var str5 = '<feFlood flood-color="#000000" flood-opacity="'+shadowOpacity+'"/>'+
    '<feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"/>'+
    '<feMerge>'+
    '<feMergeNode/>'+
    '<feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>'+
    '</feMerge>'+
    '</filter>'+
    '</defs>';
    var str8 = '</g></svg>'; 

    function dynShad (str2, str4, str6, str7) {   
        var create = str1 + str2 + str3 + str4 + str5 + str6 + str7 + str8;
        return create;
    }

    function clock() {
        var x = new Date();

        var time    = Math.min(60000, 1.025 * (1000 * x.getSeconds() + x.getMilliseconds()));
        var seconds = Math.floor(time / 1000);
        var millis  = time % 1000;
        var germanSec = (6 * seconds + 3 * (1 + Math.cos(Math.PI + Math.PI * (0.001 * millis))));
        var minutes = x.getMinutes();
        var hours = (x.getHours() * 30) + (minutes / 2);



        if (germanSec !== presec) {
            var ssy = dropShadow(germanSec, 0.7).vsa;
            var ssx = dropShadow(germanSec, 0.7).hsa;
            var sf = '<filter id="sf'+idx+'" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">';
            var se = '<g filter="url(#sf'+idx+')">';
            var ss = '<feOffset id="soffset'+idx+'" dx="'+ssx+'" dy="'+ssy+'" result="offsetblur"/>';
            secC.innerHTML = dynShad (sf, ss,se, secsvg);
            secHand.appendChild(secC);
        }
        
        if (minutes !== premin) {
            var msy = dropShadow(minutes * 6, 0.5).vsa;
            var msx = dropShadow(minutes * 6, 0.5).hsa;
            var mf = '<filter id="mf'+idx+'" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">';
            var me ='<g filter="url(#mf'+idx+')">';
            var ms = '<feOffset id="moffset'+idx+'"  dx="'+msx+'" dy="'+msy+'" result="offsetblur"/>';
            minC.innerHTML = dynShad (mf, ms,me, minsvg);
            minHand.appendChild(minC);
        }
        
        if (hours !== prehou) {
            var hsy = dropShadow(hours, 0.4).vsa;
            var hsx = dropShadow(hours, 0.4).hsa;
            var hf = '<filter id="hf'+idx+'" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">';
            var he ='<g filter="url(#hf'+idx+')">';
            var hs = '<feOffset id="hoffset'+idx+'" dx="'+hsx+'" dy="'+hsy+'" result="offsetblur"/>';
            houC.innerHTML = dynShad (hf, hs,he, housvg);
            houHand.appendChild(houC);
        }
        
        secHand.style.transform = 'rotate(' + germanSec + 'deg) translateZ(0)'; 
        minHand.style.transform = 'rotate(' + (minutes * 6) + 'deg) translateZ(0)';
        houHand.style.transform = 'rotate(' + hours + 'deg) translateZ(0)';

        presec = germanSec;
        premin = minutes;
        prehou = hours;

        tmr = setTimeout(clock, mls);
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', clock, false);
})();
```

Comment: Be careful AFIK there is a so called *Geschmacksmuster* which is holded by a Swaziland company, so you may need to play money when you want to use that design.

Comment: Why not to use <canvas> for that purpose?
There are plenty of samples : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations

Comment: @c-smile I don't think using canvas is the way to learn svg.

Comment: @MrLister What if purpose of learning includes exploration of areas of applicability of the technology?

Comment: @rekire - Yes I  heard about Apple's use of the Hilfiker/Mobatime Swiss clock. I've made that too if you want me to post it?

Comment: @c-smile - I know about canvas but I'm a JavaScript boy at heart. I can achieve pretty much everything I want to do with it. Like I said the problem I'm having is being a newbie at SVG.

Comment: @rekire Switzerland, not Swaziland ;)

Comment: @Griggy, changing the question once it has answers is not allowed.

Comment: I didn't know but I thought I left the question completely intact with an additional 'info update' at the bottom.

Comment: It moves the question away from its original root which is "how do I modify dx, dy of an feOffset". By the way, none of your self answers address that so they don't answer the question you've asked and I suspect they may attract downvotes because of that.

Answer (score 3):

> All I wanted was to dynamically access the filter feOffset's dx and dy
>   attributes to give the clock hands realistic shadow positions as they
>   move around the dial.

actually you don't have to touch the dx and dy attribute for a realistic shadow. All you have to do is to put your hands into a g-element and apply the shadow to the group (which is not rotating). in this case the shadow don't rotate and so the offset stays fixed.

see this example, where the rect is rotating, but the shadow is aplied to the group:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200" height="200">
 <defs>
  <filter id="gb" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-50" y="-50" width="100" height="100">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1" />
      <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" />
      <feMerge>
          <feMergeNode />
          <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
 </defs>
 <g transform="translate(50 50)" filter="url(#gb)">
  <rect  x="-0.5" y="-45" width="1" height="45" fill="red">
   <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0" to="360" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </rect>
 </g>
</svg>
```

```js
var r=document.getElementById("rect")

setInterval(function(){
var d = new Date();
var a = d.getSeconds()*6; // 360/60 so every second equals 6 deg
r.setAttribute("transform","rotate("+a+")");
},500);
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200" height="200">
 <defs>
  <filter id="gb" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-50" y="-50" width="100" height="100">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1" />
      <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" />
      <feMerge>
          <feMergeNode />
          <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
 </defs>
 <g transform="translate(50 50)" filter="url(#gb)">
  <rect id="rect" x="-0.5" y="-45" width="1" height="45" fill="red"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: WOW!!! That's fantastic. SVG is turning out way better than I first thought. I'm off to play with your code and thanks.

Comment: Ok, had a play with it. The 'auto shadow' only works with svg's animateTransform. However, my broswer is reporting this: SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead.

Comment: i only used animateTransform for a small and readable example. You can use any means of animation you like. I've updated the answer to include a second example wich uses js to animate the rect.

Comment: Thanks Holger, that's excellent. Like I said I'm an SVG novice but not for long I hope. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the id of the filter you can get it using document.getElementById. In your case I think that would be something like this...

```
var offset = document.getElementById('hoffset'+idx);
```

You can set and get the dx/dy using setAttribute/getAttribute e.g.

```
offset.setAttribute("dx", "13");
```

Or you can use the [SVG DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#InterfaceSVGFEOffsetElement) which will let you work with numbers rather than strings.

```
offset.dx.baseVal = 13;
```

Comment: Just tried your method and it works a treat! Now I've got some rewriting to do. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**The Original Hilfiker/MobaTime Swiss Railway Clock. 1953 version.**

```js
(function () {

    /*
    The Hilfiker/MobaTime Swiss Railway Clock
    1953 version (Stop To Go)
    kurt.grigg@yahoo.co.uk
    */

    /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Config below ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */

    var clockSize = 300;
    var caseColour = 'rgba(200,200,200,1.0)';
    var dialColour = 'rgba(235,240,240,1.0)';
    var sechandColour = 'rgba(173,26,20,1.0)';
    var handColour = 'rgb(20,20,20)';
    var markColour = 'rgb(10,10,10)';
    var reflection = '6Reflection.png';
    var clockShape = 50;
        /* (max) 50 = round  (min) 0 = square */

    /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ End config ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */

    var d = document;
    var mrkrs = [];
    var tmr;
    var mls = 50;
    var broff = (clockShape < 20) ? 2 : 0;
    var prevmin;
    var mincr = new Date().getMinutes() - 1;
    var hincr = new Date().getHours();
    var rnd = 'id'+Math.random() * 1;
    var cbcbzr = '.3s cubic-bezier(0.666, 1.91, 0.333, 0)';
    var vb = '<svg height="'+xy(100)+'" width="'+xy(100)+'" viewBox="0 0 200 200">';
    d.write('<div id = "'+rnd+'" style="display:inline-block;line-height:0px;"></div>');
    var dum = '';

    function xy (v) {
        return (v * clockSize / 100);
    }

    function genShadKillClone(c, v, x, y) {
        c.style.left = xy(x)+'px';
        c.style.top = xy(y)+'px';
        c.style.zIndex--;   
        var s = 'filter="url(#handShadow)"';
        var r = v.split('filter="url()"').join("");
        r = r.replace(/""/g, s);
        c.innerHTML = r;
    }

    /* Clock case and dial */

    var outerRim = d.createElement('div');
    outerRim.setAttribute('style', 'display:inline-block;'
        +'position: relative;'
        +'height: '+xy(116)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(116)+'px;'
        +'background-image: linear-gradient(to left, '
        +'rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0%, '
        +'rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 50%, '
        +'rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 100%);'
        +'background-color: '+caseColour+';'
        +'border: '+xy(1)+'px solid transparent;' 
        +'box-shadow: 0 0 '+xy(0.5)+'px '+xy(0.05)+'px rgba(255,255,255,0.7), '
        +'0 '+xy(6)+'px '+xy(1)+'px -'+xy(1)+'px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);'
        +'border-radius: '+clockShape+'%;');
    d.getElementById(rnd).appendChild(outerRim);

    var innerRim = d.createElement('div');
    innerRim.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;'
        +'position: absolute;'
        +'height: '+xy(113.8)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(113.8)+'px;'
        +'background-color: '+dialColour+';'
        +'margin: auto; top: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;' 
        +'box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 '+xy(2.9)+'px rgba(30,30,30,0.3),'
        +'inset 0 '+xy(3)+'px '+xy(5)+'px '+xy(3)+'px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);'
        +'border-radius: '+clockShape+'%;'
        +'border: '+xy(0.2)+'px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.05);');
    outerRim.appendChild(innerRim);

    var dial = d.createElement('div');
    dial.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;'
        +'position: absolute;'
        +'height: '+xy(100)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(100)+'px;'
        +'margin: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;' 
        +'border-radius: '+clockShape+'%;'
        +'overflow: hidden;');
    innerRim.appendChild(dial);

    /* Clock markers  */
    var face = '<svg id="MobaTimeClock" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"'+ 
        'viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="100%" height="100%">'+
        '<defs>'+
        '<clipPath id="dialPath">'+
         '<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100"/>'+
        '</clipPath>'+
        '</defs>'+
        '<filter id="handShadow" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">'+
         '<feFlood result="flood" flood-color="#000" flood-opacity=".4"/>'+
         '<feComposite result="composite1" operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" in="flood"/>'+
         '<feGaussianBlur result="blur" stdDeviation="0.5" in="composite1"/>'+
         '<feOffset result="offset" dy="0" dx="0"/>'+
         '<feComposite result="composite2" operator="atop" in2="offset" in="offset"/>'+
        '</filter>'+
        '</svg>';
    dial.innerHTML = face;

    for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {

        var mrkrLength = (i % 5) ? 7.5 : 25;
        var mrkrWidth = (i % 5) ? 3 : 7.5;

        mrkrs[i] = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'line');
        with(mrkrs[i]) {
            setAttribute('x1', '100');
            setAttribute('y1', '0');
            setAttribute('x2', '100');
            setAttribute('y2', mrkrLength);
            setAttribute('stroke', markColour);
            setAttribute('stroke-width', mrkrWidth);
            setAttribute('stroke-linecap', 'butt');
            setAttribute("clip-path", "url(#dialPath)");
            setAttribute( "transform","rotate("+i * 6+", 100, 100)");
        }
        MobaTimeClock.appendChild(mrkrs[i]);
    }

    var logo = '<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 160 106" ' +
    'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">' +
    '<path d="M72.764.744C74.936.347 77.136 0 79.35.052c.94.017 1.88.01 2.82.08 4.8' +
    '35.364 9.615 1.48 14.098 3.357 4.685 1.99 9.022 4.85 12.635 8.467 3.488 3.46 6' +
    '.303 7.605 8.27 12.123 1.837 4.26 2.964 8.834 3.284 13.47.3 4.69-.077 9.427-1.' +
    '208 13.988-.398 1.737-.95 3.43-1.494 5.126-3.685-2.417-7.306-4.932-10.977-7.37' +
    '.638-2.657 1.03-5.388.955-8.128-.032-2.894-.504-5.78-1.35-8.545-1.36-4.383-3.75' +
    '-8.47-7.038-11.658-3.758-3.765-8.715-6.24-13.914-7.168-2.006-.367-4.047-.537-6' +
    '.083-.51-2.38.167-4.755.56-7.04 1.256-.07.018-.212.05-.282.067-4.875 1.52-9.37' +
    ' 4.36-12.692 8.292-3.532 4.122-5.726 9.365-6.367 14.77-.3 2.187-.26 4.41-.16 6' +
    '.61.152 1.61.355 3.218.707 4.797-3.644 2.364-7.266 4.76-10.93 7.09-1.812-4.79-' +
    '2.977-9.862-3.083-15.002-.237-8.587 2.43-17.226 7.466-24.152C51.114 11.27 56.7' +
    '94 6.69 63.212 3.79c3.06-1.366 6.266-2.402 9.552-3.046z" fill-opacity=".9" fill="'+markColour+'"/>' +
    '<path d="M48.772 76.595L55.83 71.9l1.774 1.816c1.023 1.047 2.286 2.145 2.984 2' +
    '.595 5.233 3.37 12.434 5.067 20.513 4.835 3.703-.106 5.01-.245 8.036-.856 2.72' +
    '-.55 5.2-1.387 7.582-2.557 2.47-1.213 4.22-2.505 5.976-4.41l1.357-1.47 7.045 4' +
    '.715 7.045 4.715 11.09.06c6.934.038 11.03.002 10.926-.096-.828-.782-35.83-26.7' +
    '53-35.916-26.648-4.85 5.9-8.918 9.252-13.73 11.313-3.472 1.487-6.387 2.055-10.' +
    '566 2.058-9.514.007-16.507-3.84-24.292-13.368-.08-.096-31.817 23.46-35.66 26.4' +
    '67-.395.308-.217.312 10.66.266l11.064-.047 7.056-4.695z" fill="url(#a)"/>' +
    '<path d="M81.42 90.82h-3.505l-5.58 15.26h3.473l1.078-2.32 5.597.02 1.08 2.302h' +
    '3.32l-5.462-15.26zm-1.717 4.213l1.667 5.944h-3.285l1.618-5.944zm-22.434-4.23h-' +
    '5.174v15.26l6.303.016c1.6.02 3.624-1.607 3.994-3.73.084-2.25-.845-4.16-2.376-4' +
    '.446.876-.41 1.45-1.89 1.348-3.854-.238-1.944-2.26-3.392-4.097-3.248m.976 3.73' +
    'c.353.662.153 1.337-.05 1.837-.656.768-1.837.714-2.78.714v-3.302c.842 0 2.308-' +
    '.16 2.83.75m.625 5.747c.37.606.286 1.73.103 2.16-.893.998-2.16.962-3.523.8v-3.' +
    '604c1.618-.108 2.46-.09 3.42.643M15.118 90.8l2.41 15.24-3 .037-1.432-8.89-3.75' +
    '8 8.89-.926-.037-3.675-8.496-1.517 8.532L0 106.042l2.36-15.277h3.17l3.166 8.744' +
    ' 3.42-8.708h3zm19.23 11.673c-2.29 0-4.18-2-4.18-4.427 0-2.427 1.89-4.425 4.18-' +
    '4.425 2.293 0 4.18 1.998 4.18 4.425 0 2.426-1.887 4.427-4.18 4.427m0 3.604c4.2' +
    '8 0 7.77-3.605 7.77-8.032 0-4.425-3.49-8.048-7.77-8.048-4.28 0-7.768 3.623-7.7' +
    '68 8.048 0 4.427 3.488 8.03 7.768 8.03M98.68 91.482h8.56l-.285 1.68h-3.49l-1.8' +
    '87 12.883h-1.754l1.924-12.884h-3.374l.306-1.68zm18.623 0h1.753l-2.19 14.563h-1' +
    '.738l2.175-14.562zm24.506-1.017l.756 15.58h-1.99l-.115-9.94-5.898 10.242-2.715' +
    '-10.242-3.166 9.94h-1.972l5.444-15.58 3 11.796 6.657-11.797zm18.236 1.018l-.43' +
    '8 1.68h-5.648l-.608 4.086h5.546l-.32 1.66h-5.494l-.876 5.46h5.798l-.286 1.677h' +
    '-7.55l2.174-14.562h7.702z" fill-opacity="1.0" fill="'+markColour+'"/>' + 
    '<defs>' +
    '<pattern xlink:href="#b" id="a" patternTransform="translate(364.52 610.068) scale(6.07904)"/>' +
    '<pattern id="b" patternTransform="scale(10)" height="1" width="1.07" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">' +
    '<path fill="'+markColour+'" d="M0 0h.5v1H0z"/>' + 
    '</pattern>' + 
    '</defs>' + 
    '</svg>';

    var mtl = d.createElement('div');
    mtl.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;'
        +'position: absolute;'
        +'height: '+xy(9)+'px;'
        +'top: '+xy(68)+'px;'
        +'paddingBottom: '+xy(1)+'px;'
        +'margin: auto; left: 0;right: 0;');
    mtl.innerHTML = logo;
    dial.appendChild(mtl);

    /* Generic container for all hands */

    var handContainers = 'display: block;'
        +'position: absolute;'
        +'height: '+xy(100)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(100)+'px;'
        +'font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px; padding: 0;'
        +'margin: auto; top: 0;bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;'
        +'transform-origin: center center;'

    /* Hour hand */

    var houContainer = d.createElement('div');
    houContainer.setAttribute('style', handContainers + 'transition: '+cbcbzr+';');
    houContainer.style.zIndex = 50;
    dial.appendChild(houContainer);
    var houHand = d.createElement('div');
    var housvg = vb +
    '<polygon points="95,33 105,33 106,125 94,125"  transform="translate(0,2)" fill="'+handColour+'" stroke="none" "'+dum+'" />'+
    '</svg>';
    houHand.innerHTML = housvg;
    houContainer.appendChild(houHand);
    var houShad = houContainer.cloneNode(true);
    dial.appendChild(houShad);
    genShadKillClone(houShad,housvg, 0, 3);

    /* Minute hand */

    var minContainer = d.createElement('div');
    minContainer.setAttribute('style',handContainers + 'transition: '+cbcbzr+';');
    minContainer.style.zIndex = 52;
    dial.appendChild(minContainer);
    var minHand = d.createElement('div');
    var minsvg =  vb +
    '<polygon points="96,5 104,5 105,125 95,125" transform="translate(0,2)" fill="'+handColour+'" stroke="none" "'+dum+'" />'+
    '</svg>';
    minHand.innerHTML = minsvg;
    minContainer.appendChild(minHand);
    var minShad = minContainer.cloneNode(true);
    dial.appendChild(minShad);
    genShadKillClone(minShad,minsvg, 0, 4);

    /* Seconds hand */

    var secContainer = d.createElement('div');
    secContainer.setAttribute('style',handContainers);
    secContainer.style.zIndex = 54;
    dial.appendChild(secContainer);
    var secHand = d.createElement('div');
    var secsvg =  vb +
    '<path d="M100 23.475a10 10 0 0 0-10 10 10 10 0 0 0 8.22 9.832V135h3.56V43.31a10 10 0 0 0 8.22-9.835 10 10 0 0 0-10-10z"  transform="translate(0,1)" fill="'+sechandColour+'" "'+dum+'" />'+
    '</svg>';
    secHand.innerHTML = secsvg;
    secContainer.appendChild(secHand);
    var secShad = secContainer.cloneNode(true);
    dial.appendChild(secShad);
    genShadKillClone(secShad,secsvg, 0, 5);

    var glass = d.createElement('div');
    glass.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;'
        +'position: absolute;'
        +'height: '+xy(112)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(112)+'px;'
        +'margin: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;right: 0;' 
        +'border-radius: '+clockShape+'%;'
        +'background-image: url("http://i61.tinypic.com/300xjcn.png");'
        +'background-size: cover;'
        +'opacity: 0.3;'
        +'z-index: 55;'
        +'overflow: hidden;');
    innerRim.appendChild(glass);

    function clock() {
        var x = new Date();

        var StopToGo = (Math.min((x.getSeconds() + x.getMilliseconds() / 1000) * (60 / 58.5), 60));

        var presmin = x.getMinutes();
        if (presmin !== prevmin) {
            mincr++;
        }
        prevmin = presmin;

        secContainer.style.transform = 'rotate(' + (StopToGo * 6) + 'deg) translateZ(0)'; 
         secShad.style.transform = 'rotate(' + (StopToGo * 6) + 'deg) translateZ(0)'; 
        minContainer.style.transform = 'rotate(' + (mincr * 6) + 'deg) translateZ(0)';
         minShad.style.transform = 'rotate(' + (mincr * 6) + 'deg) translateZ(0)';
        houContainer.style.transform = 'rotate(' + ((hincr * 30) + (mincr / 2)) + 'deg) translateZ(0)';
         houShad.style.transform = 'rotate(' + ((hincr * 30) + (mincr / 2)) + 'deg) translateZ(0)';

        tmr = setTimeout(clock, mls);
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', clock, false);

})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hilfiker MobaTime Swiss Railway Clock</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: rgb(205,179,139);
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**German railway T&N station clock**

```js
(function () {

    /*
    German Railway Clock
    
    kurt.grigg@yahoo.co.uk
    */

    /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Config below ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */

    var clockSize = 300;
    var caseColour = 'rgb(20,20,20)';
    var dialColour = 'rgba(235,240,240,1.0)';
    var sechandColour = 'rgba(173,26,20,1.0)';
    var handColour = 'rgb(30,30,30)';
    var markColour = 'rgb(10,10,10)';
    var reflection = '6Reflection.png';
    var clockShape = 50;
        /* (max) 50 = round  (min) 0 = square */

    /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ End config ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */

    var d = document;
    var mrkrs = [];
    var tmr;
    var mls = 50;
    var broff = (clockShape < 20) ? 2 : 0;
    var prevmin;
    var mincr = new Date().getMinutes() - 1;
    var hincr = new Date().getHours();
    var rnd = 'id'+Math.random() * 1;
    var cbcbzr = '.4s cubic-bezier(0.666, 1.91, 0.333, 0)';
    var dum = '';
    var vb = '<svg height="'+xy(100)+'" width="'+xy(100)+'" viewBox="0 0 200 200">';
    d.write('<div id = "'+rnd+'" style="display:inline-block;line-height:0px;"></div>');

    function xy (v) {
        return (v * clockSize / 100);
    }

    function genShadKillClone(c, v, x, y) {
        c.style.left = xy(x)+'px';
        c.style.top = xy(y)+'px';
        c.style.zIndex--;   
        var s = 'filter="url(#handShadow)"';
        var r = v.split('filter="url()"').join("");
        r = r.replace(/""/g, s);
        c.innerHTML = r;
    }

    /* Clock case and dial */

    var outerRim = d.createElement('div');
    outerRim.setAttribute('style', 'display:inline-block;'
        +'position: relative;'
        +'height: '+xy(115)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(115)+'px;'
        +'background-image: linear-gradient(to left, '
        +'rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 5%, '
        +'rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 50%, '
        +'rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 95%);'
        +'background-color: '+caseColour+';'
        +'border: '+xy(1)+'px solid transparent;' 
        +'box-shadow: 0 0 '+xy(0.5)+'px '+xy(0.05)+'px rgba(255,255,255,0.7), '
        +'0 '+xy(6)+'px '+xy(1)+'px -'+xy(1)+'px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);'
        +'border-radius: '+clockShape+'%;');
    d.getElementById(rnd).appendChild(outerRim);

    var innerRim = d.createElement('div');
    innerRim.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;'
        +'position: absolute;'
        +'height: '+xy(109.8)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(109.8)+'px;'
        +'background-color: '+dialColour+';'
        +'margin: auto; top: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;' 
        +'box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 '+xy(3.0)+'px rgba(50,50,50,0.15),'
        +'inset 0 '+xy(6)+'px '+xy(5)+'px '+xy(4)+'px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);'
        +'border-radius: '+clockShape+'%;'
        +'border: '+xy(0.2)+'px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.05);');
    outerRim.appendChild(innerRim);

    var dial = d.createElement('div');
    dial.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;'
        +'position: absolute;'
        +'height: '+xy(100)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(100)+'px;'
        +'margin: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;' 
        +'border-radius: '+clockShape+'%;'
        +'overflow: hidden;');
    innerRim.appendChild(dial);

    /* Clock markers  */
    var face = '<svg id="TNClock" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"'+ 
        'viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="100%" height="100%">'+
        '<defs>'+
        '<clipPath id="dialPath">'+
         '<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100"/>'+
        '</clipPath>'+
        '</defs>'+
        '<filter id="handShadow" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">'+
         '<feFlood result="flood" flood-color="#000" flood-opacity=".4"/>'+
         '<feComposite result="composite1" operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" in="flood"/>'+
         '<feGaussianBlur result="blur" stdDeviation="0.5" in="composite1"/>'+
         '<feOffset result="offset" dy="0" dx="0"/>'+
         '<feComposite result="composite2" operator="atop" in2="offset" in="offset"/>'+
        '</filter>'+
        '<g id="TNLogo" transform="translate(87.4,141.2) scale(0.5, 0.5)">'+
         '<path stroke="#000" fill="none" d="M2.732 19L25 2.06 47.268 19 25 35.94 2.732 19z"/>'+
         '<path d="M17.194 10.2h15.612v2.298h-6.713v17.727h-2.186V12.498h-6.713V10.2z"/>'+
         '<path d="M17.975 14.95l11.865 8.864V14.95h2.185v13.13L20.16 19.22v8.863h-2.185V14.95z"/>'+
        '</g>'+
        '</svg>';
    dial.innerHTML = face;

    for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        var mrkrLength = 30;
        if (i % 15) {
            mrkrLength = 24;
        }
        if (i % 5) { 
            mrkrLength = 8;
        }
        var mrkrWidth = (i % 5) ? 3.6 : 8.8;

        mrkrs[i] = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'line');
        with(mrkrs[i]) {
            setAttribute('x1', '100');
            setAttribute('y1', '0');
            setAttribute('x2', '100');
            setAttribute('y2', mrkrLength);
            setAttribute('stroke', markColour);
            setAttribute('stroke-width', mrkrWidth);
            setAttribute('stroke-linecap', 'butt');
            setAttribute("clip-path", "url(#dialPath)");
            setAttribute( "transform","rotate("+i * 6+", 100, 100)");
        }
        TNClock.appendChild(mrkrs[i]);
    }

    /* Generic container for all hands */

    var handContainers = 'display: block;'
        +'position: absolute;'
        +'height: '+xy(100)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(100)+'px;'
        +'font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px; padding: 0;'
        +'margin: auto; top: 0;bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;'
        +'transform-origin: center center;'

    /* Hour hand */

    var houContainer = d.createElement('div');
    houContainer.setAttribute('style', handContainers + 'transition: '+cbcbzr+';');
    houContainer.style.zIndex = 50;
    dial.appendChild(houContainer);
    var houHand = d.createElement('div');
    var housvg = vb +
    '<polygon points="94,46 100,40 106,46 106,118 94,118" fill="'+handColour+'" stroke="none" "'+dum+'" />'+
    '</svg>';
    houHand.innerHTML = housvg;
    houContainer.appendChild(houHand);
    var houShad = houContainer.cloneNode(true);
    dial.appendChild(houShad);
    genShadKillClone(houShad,housvg, 0, 3);

    /* Minute hand */

    var minContainer = d.createElement('div');
    minContainer.setAttribute('style',handContainers + 'transition: '+cbcbzr+';');
    minContainer.style.zIndex = 52;
    dial.appendChild(minContainer);
    var minHand = d.createElement('div');
    var minsvg =  vb +
    '<polygon points="95.5,11.5 100,7 104.5,11.5 104.5,122 95.5,122" fill="'+handColour+'" stroke="none" "'+dum+'" />'+
    '</svg>';
    minHand.innerHTML = minsvg;
    minContainer.appendChild(minHand);
    var minShad = minContainer.cloneNode(true);
    dial.appendChild(minShad);
    genShadKillClone(minShad,minsvg, 0, 4);

    /* Seconds hand */

    var secContainer = d.createElement('div');
    secContainer.setAttribute('style',handContainers);
    secContainer.style.zIndex = 54;
    dial.appendChild(secContainer);

    var secHand = d.createElement('div');
    var secsvg =  vb +
    '<path d="M100 9.05l-1.2 1.2-.355 27.367c-5.724.77-10.195 5.71-10.195 11.633 0 5.792 4.275 10.643 9.816 11.576L97.5 121.25h5l-.568-60.424c5.54-.933 9.818-5.784 9.818-11.576 0-5.923-4.473-10.862-10.197-11.633L101.2 10.25zM100 44c2.938 0 5.25 2.312 5.25 5.25s-2.312 5.25-5.25 5.25-5.25-2.312-5.25-5.25S97.062 44 100 44z" fill="'+sechandColour+'" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" "'+dum+'" />'+
    '</svg>';
    secHand.innerHTML = secsvg;
    secContainer.appendChild(secHand);
    var secShad = secContainer.cloneNode(true);
    dial.appendChild(secShad);
    genShadKillClone(secShad,secsvg, 0, 5);

    var glass = d.createElement('div');
    glass.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;'
        +'position: absolute;'
        +'height: '+xy(108.8)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(108.8)+'px;'
        +'margin: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;right: 0;' 
        +'border: '+xy(0.2)+'px solid #000;'
        +'border-radius: '+clockShape+'%;'
        +'background-image: url("http://i61.tinypic.com/300xjcn.png");'
        +'background-size: cover;'
        +'opacity: 0.3;'
        +'z-index: 55;'
        +'overflow: hidden;');
    innerRim.appendChild(glass);

    function clock() {
        var x = new Date();

        var time    = Math.min(60000, 1.025 * (1000 * x.getSeconds() + x.getMilliseconds()));
        var seconds = Math.floor(time / 1000);
        var millis  = time % 1000;
        var germanSec = (6 * seconds + 3 * (1 + Math.cos(Math.PI + Math.PI * (0.001 * millis))));
        
        var presmin = x.getMinutes();
        if (presmin !== prevmin) {
            mincr++;
        }
        prevmin = presmin;

        secContainer.style.transform = 'rotate(' + germanSec + 'deg) translateZ(0)'; 
         secShad.style.transform = 'rotate(' + germanSec + 'deg) translateZ(0)'; 
        minContainer.style.transform = 'rotate(' + (mincr * 6) + 'deg) translateZ(0)';
         minShad.style.transform = 'rotate(' + (mincr * 6) + 'deg) translateZ(0)';
        houContainer.style.transform = 'rotate(' + ((hincr * 30) + (mincr / 2)) + 'deg) translateZ(0)';
         houShad.style.transform = 'rotate(' + ((hincr * 30) + (mincr / 2)) + 'deg) translateZ(0)';

        tmr = setTimeout(clock, mls);
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', clock, false);
})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>German Railway Clock</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: rgb(205,179,139);
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Deutsche Bahn Clock - Modern.**

```js
(function () {

    /*
    Deutsche Bahn Clock
    kurt.grigg@yahoo.co.uk
    */

    /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Config below ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */

    var clockSize = 300;
    var caseColour = 'rgb(0,0,120)';
    var dialColour = 'rgba(235,240,240,1.0)';
    var sechandColour = 'rgba(173,26,20,1.0)';
    var handColour = 'rgb(30,30,30)';
    var markColour = 'rgb(10,10,10)';
    var handShadowColour = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)';
    var reflection = '6Reflection.png';
    var clockShape = 50;
        /* (max) 50 = round  (min) 0 = square */

    /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ End config ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */

    var d = document;
    var mrkrs = [];
    var tmr;
    var mls = 50;
    var broff = (clockShape < 20) ? 2 : 0;
    var prevmin;
    var mincr = new Date().getMinutes() - 1;
    var hincr = new Date().getHours();
    var rnd = 'id'+Math.random() * 1;
    var dum = '';
    var cbcbzr = '.3s cubic-bezier(0.666, 1.91, 0.333, 0)';
    var vb = '<svg height="'+xy(100)+'" width="'+xy(100)+'" viewBox="0 0 200 200">';
    d.write('<div id = "'+rnd+'" style="display:inline-block;line-height:0px;"></div>');

    function xy (v) {
        return (v * clockSize / 100);
    }

    function genShadKillClone(c, v, x, y) {
        c.style.left = xy(x)+'px';
        c.style.top = xy(y)+'px';
        c.style.zIndex--;   
        var s = 'filter="url(#handShadow)"';
        var r = v.split('filter="url()"').join("");
        r = r.replace(/""/g, s);
        c.innerHTML = r;
    }

    /* Clock case and dial */

    var outerRim = d.createElement('div');
    outerRim.setAttribute('style', 'display:inline-block;'
        +'position: relative;'
        +'height: '+xy(115)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(115)+'px;'
        +'background-image: linear-gradient(to left, '
        +'rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 5%, '
        +'rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 50%, '
        +'rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 95%);'
        +'background-color: '+caseColour+';'
        +'border: '+xy(0.5)+'px solid transparent;' 
        +'box-shadow: inset 0 0 '+xy(2)+'px '+xy(0.3)+'px rgba(255,255,255,0.5),'
        +' 0 '+xy(6)+'px '+xy(1)+'px -'+xy(1)+'px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);'
        +'border-radius: '+clockShape+'%;');
    d.getElementById(rnd).appendChild(outerRim);

    var innerRim = d.createElement('div');
    innerRim.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;'
        +'position: absolute;'
        +'height: '+xy(109.8)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(109.8)+'px;'
        +'background-color: '+dialColour+';'
        +'margin: auto; top: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;' 
        +'box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 '+xy(3.0)+'px rgba(50,50,50,0.15),'
        +'inset 0 '+xy(6)+'px '+xy(5)+'px '+xy(4)+'px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);'
        +'border-radius: '+clockShape+'%;'
        +'border: '+xy(0.2)+'px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.05);');
    outerRim.appendChild(innerRim);

    var dial = d.createElement('div');
    dial.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;'
        +'position: absolute;'
        +'height: '+xy(100)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(100)+'px;'
        +'margin: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;' 
        +'border-radius: '+clockShape+'%;'
        +'overflow: hidden;');
    innerRim.appendChild(dial);

    /* Clock markers  */
    var face = '<svg id="DBClock" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"'+ 
        'viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="100%" height="100%">'+
        '<defs>'+
        '<clipPath id="dialPath">'+
         '<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100"/>'+
        '</clipPath>'+
        '</defs>'+
        '<filter id="handShadow" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">'+
         '<feFlood result="flood" flood-color="#000" flood-opacity=".4"/>'+
         '<feComposite result="composite1" operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" in="flood"/>'+
         '<feGaussianBlur result="blur" stdDeviation="0.5" in="composite1"/>'+
         '<feOffset result="offset" dy="0" dx="0"/>'+
         '<feComposite result="composite2" operator="atop" in2="offset" in="offset"/>'+
        '</filter>'+
        '<g id="DBLogo" transform="translate(89.2,35.5) scale(0.5, 0.5)">'+
         '<path fill="none" d="M40.26 27.83H2.49V1.964h37.77V27.83z"/>'+
         '<path fill="'+sechandColour+'" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.916'+
         ' 5.233h7.566c4.72 0 7.494 3.044 7.494 9.614 0 6.997-2.9 9.8-'+
         '7.494 9.8H5.916V5.232zm17.18 0h8.46c3.542 0 5.32 2.134 5.32 '+
         '4.594 0 3.228-1.892 4.323-3.356 4.636v.085c2.19.285 4.167 1.'+
         '835 4.167 4.807-.015 3.2-2.333 5.29-6.656 5.29h-7.935V5.234z'+
         'm-12.5 3.044h1.663c2.687 0 4.11 1.934 4.11 6.485 0 5.22-1.66'+
         '5 6.783-4.026 6.783h-1.75V8.277zm17.136-.03h1.79c1.836 0 2.5'+
         '9 1.025 2.59 2.22 0 1.45-.782 2.46-2.617 2.46h-1.763v-4.68zm'+
         '0 8.335h2.204c2.176 0 2.76 1.052 2.76 2.432 0 1.607-1.167 2.'+
         '53-2.732 2.53h-2.232v-4.962zM4.394 0h34.203c2.432 0 4.408 1.'+
         '963 4.408 4.394v20.99c0 2.433-1.976 4.41-4.408 4.41H4.394c-2'+
         '.43 0-4.394-1.977-4.394-4.41V4.395C0 1.964 1.963 0 4.394 0zm'+
         '.057 3h34.104c.754 0 1.365.612 1.365 1.366v21.048c0 .753-.61'+
         '2 1.365-1.366 1.365H4.45c-.752 0-1.364-.613-1.364-1.366V4.36'+
         '6C3.086 3.612 3.698 3 4.45 3"/></g></svg>';
    dial.innerHTML = face;

    for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        var mrkrLength = 30;
        if (i % 15) {
            mrkrLength = 24;
        }
        if (i % 5) { 
            mrkrLength = 8;
        }
        var mrkrWidth = (i % 5) ? 3.6 : 8.8;

        mrkrs[i] = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'line');
        with(mrkrs[i]) {
            setAttribute('x1', '100');
            setAttribute('y1', '0');
            setAttribute('x2', '100');
            setAttribute('y2', mrkrLength);
            setAttribute('stroke', markColour);
            setAttribute('stroke-width', mrkrWidth);
            setAttribute('stroke-linecap', 'butt');
            setAttribute("clip-path", "url(#dialPath)");
            setAttribute( "transform","rotate("+i * 6+", 100, 100)");
        }
        DBClock.appendChild(mrkrs[i]);
    }

    /* Generic container for all hands */

    var handContainers = 'display: block;'
        +'position: absolute;'
        +'height: '+xy(100)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(100)+'px;'
        +'font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px; padding: 0;'
        +'margin: auto; top: 0;bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;'
        +'transform-origin: center center;'

    /* Hour hand */

    var houContainer = d.createElement('div');
    houContainer.setAttribute('style', handContainers + 'transition: '+cbcbzr+';');
    houContainer.style.zIndex = 50;
    dial.appendChild(houContainer);
    var houHand = d.createElement('div');
    var housvg = vb +
    '<rect x="95" y="40" width="10" height="58" stroke="none" fill="'+handColour+'" "'+dum+'" />'+
    '</svg>';
    houHand.innerHTML = housvg;
    houContainer.appendChild(houHand);
    var houShad = houContainer.cloneNode(true);
    dial.appendChild(houShad);
    genShadKillClone(houShad,housvg, 0, 3);

    /* Minute hand */

    var minContainer = d.createElement('div');
    minContainer.setAttribute('style',handContainers + 'transition: '+cbcbzr+';');
    minContainer.style.zIndex = 52;
    dial.appendChild(minContainer);
    var minHand = d.createElement('div');
    var minsvg =  vb +
    '<rect x="96" y="6" width="8" height="92" fill="'+handColour+'" stroke="none" "'+dum+'" />'+
    '</svg>';
    minHand.innerHTML = minsvg;
    minContainer.appendChild(minHand);
    var minShad = minContainer.cloneNode(true);
    dial.appendChild(minShad);
    genShadKillClone(minShad,minsvg, 0, 4);

    /* Seconds hand */

    var secContainer = d.createElement('div');
    secContainer.setAttribute('style',handContainers);
    secContainer.style.zIndex = 54;
    dial.appendChild(secContainer);

    var secHand = d.createElement('div');
    var secsvg =  vb +
    '<path d="M98 2l-.275 29.223C92.2 32.293 88 37.173 88 43c0 5.744 4'+
    '.084 10.57 9.492 11.73L97 100h6l-.482-45.27C107.92 53.563 112 48.'+
    '74 112 43c0-5.826-4.203-10.707-9.727-11.777L102 2h-4zm2 33c4.442 '+
    '0 8 3.558 8 8s-3.558 8-8 8-8-3.558-8-8 3.558-8 8-8z" fill="'+sechandColour+'" "'+dum+'"/></svg>';
    secHand.innerHTML = secsvg;
    secContainer.appendChild(secHand);
    var secShad = secContainer.cloneNode(true);
    dial.appendChild(secShad);
    genShadKillClone(secShad,secsvg, 0, 5);

    var nut = d.createElement('div');
    nut.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;'
        +'position: absolute;'
        +'height: '+xy(10)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(10)+'px;'
        +'border-radius: 50%;'
        +'margin: auto;top: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;'
        +'background: '+handColour+';'
        +'box-shadow: 0 '+xy(2)+'px '+xy(1)+'px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);'
        +'z-index: 56;');
    innerRim.appendChild(nut);

    var glass = d.createElement('div');
    glass.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;'
        +'position: absolute;'
        +'height: '+xy(108.8)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(108.8)+'px;'
        +'margin: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;right: 0;' 
        +'border: '+xy(0.2)+'px solid #000;'
        +'border-radius: '+clockShape+'%;'
        +'background-image: url("http://i61.tinypic.com/300xjcn.png");'
        +'background-size: cover;'
        +'opacity: 0.25;'
        +'z-index: 57;'
        +'overflow: hidden;');
    innerRim.appendChild(glass);

    function clock() {
        var x = new Date();

        var time    = Math.min(60000, 1.025 * (1000 * x.getSeconds() + x.getMilliseconds()));
        var seconds = Math.floor(time / 1000);
        var millis  = time % 1000;
        var germanSec = (6 * seconds + 3 * (1 + Math.cos(Math.PI + Math.PI * (0.001 * millis))));
        
        var presmin = x.getMinutes();
        if (presmin !== prevmin) {
            mincr++;
        }
        prevmin = presmin;

        secContainer.style.transform = 'rotate(' + germanSec + 'deg) translateZ(0)'; 
         secShad.style.transform = 'rotate(' + germanSec + 'deg) translateZ(0)'; 
        minContainer.style.transform = 'rotate(' + (mincr * 6) + 'deg) translateZ(0)';
         minShad.style.transform = 'rotate(' + (mincr * 6) + 'deg) translateZ(0)';
        houContainer.style.transform = 'rotate(' + ((hincr * 30) + (mincr / 2)) + 'deg) translateZ(0)';
         houShad.style.transform = 'rotate(' + ((hincr * 30) + (mincr / 2)) + 'deg) translateZ(0)';

        tmr = setTimeout(clock, mls);
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', clock, false);
})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Deutsche Bahn Clock</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: rgb(205,179,139);
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

**The Hilfiker/MobaTime Swiss Railway Clock
Exaggerated step and bounce on all hands**

```js
(function () {

    /*
    The Hilfiker/MobaTime Swiss Railway Clock
    1953 version (Stop To Go)
    (Exaggerated) step and bounce on all hands
    kurt.grigg@yahoo.co.uk
    */

    /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Config below ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */

    var clockSize = 300;
    var caseColour = 'rgba(200,200,200,1.0)';
    var dialColour = 'rgba(235,240,240,1.0)';
    var sechandColour = 'rgba(173,26,20,1.0)';
    var handColour = 'rgb(20,20,20)';
    var markColour = 'rgb(10,10,10)';
    var handShadowColour = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)';
    var reflection = '6Reflection.png';
    var clockShape = 50;
        /* (max) 50 = round  (min) 0 = square */

    /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ End config ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */

    var mls = 100;
    var secSpan = '.8s';
    var minSpan = '1.0s';
    var houSpan = '1.2s';
    var secIncr = 0;
    var minIncr = 0;
    var houIncr = 0;
    var d = document;
    var mrkrs = [];
    var broff = (clockShape < 20) ? 2 : 0;
    var rndId = 'id'+Math.random() * 1;
    var idx = d.getElementsByTagName('div').length;
    var secDeg, minDeg, houDeg, preSec, preMin, preHou;
    var rnd = 'id'+Math.random() * 1;
    var dum = '';
    var vb = '<svg height="'+xy(100)+'" width="'+xy(100)+'" viewBox="0 0 200 200">';
    var mobasec = new Date().getSeconds();
    var mobaoffset = (58.5/60);
    var initcyc = mobaoffset * mobasec;
    var mobacycle = 1000 - initcyc;   
    var tmr, mobaTimer; 
    var firstrun = true;
    var eiatf = 'translateZ(0); animation-timing-function: ease-in';
    var eoatf = 'translateZ(0); animation-timing-function: ease-out';
    d.write('<div id = "'+rnd+'" style="display:inline-block;line-height:0px;"></div>');

    function xy (v) {
        return (v * clockSize / 100);
    }

    function genShadKillClone(c, v, x, y) {
        c.style.left = xy(x)+'px';
        c.style.top = xy(y)+'px';
        c.style.zIndex--;   
        var s = 'filter="url(#handShadow)"';
        var r = v.split('filter="url()"').join("");
        r = r.replace(/""/g, s);
        c.innerHTML = r;
    }

    /* Clock case and dial */

    var outerRim = d.createElement('div');
    outerRim.setAttribute('style', 'display:inline-block;'
        +'position: relative;'
        +'height: '+xy(116)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(116)+'px;'
        +'background-image: linear-gradient(to left, '
        +'rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0%, '
        +'rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 50%, '
        +'rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 100%);'
        +'background-color: '+caseColour+';'
        +'border: '+xy(1)+'px solid transparent;' 
        +'box-shadow: 0 0 '+xy(0.5)+'px '+xy(0.05)+'px rgba(255,255,255,0.7), '
        +'0 '+xy(6)+'px '+xy(1)+'px -'+xy(1)+'px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);'
        +'border-radius: '+clockShape+'%;');
    d.getElementById(rnd).appendChild(outerRim);

    var innerRim = d.createElement('div');
    innerRim.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;'
        +'position: absolute;'
        +'height: '+xy(113.8)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(113.8)+'px;'
        +'background-color: '+dialColour+';'
        +'margin: auto; top: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;' 
        +'box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 '+xy(2.9)+'px rgba(30,30,30,0.3),'
        +'inset 0 '+xy(3)+'px '+xy(5)+'px '+xy(3)+'px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);'
        +'border-radius: '+clockShape+'%;'
        +'border: '+xy(0.2)+'px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.05);');
    outerRim.appendChild(innerRim);

    var dial = d.createElement('div');
    dial.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;'
        +'position: absolute;'
        +'height: '+xy(100)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(100)+'px;'
        +'margin: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;' 
        +'border-radius: '+clockShape+'%;'
        +'overflow: hidden;');
    innerRim.appendChild(dial);

    /* Clock markers  */
    var face = '<svg id="MobaTimeClock" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"'+ 
        'viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="100%" height="100%">'+
        '<defs>'+
        '<clipPath id="dialPath">'+
         '<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100"/>'+
        '</clipPath>'+
        '</defs>'+
        '<filter id="handShadow" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">'+
         '<feFlood result="flood" flood-color="#000" flood-opacity=".4"/>'+
         '<feComposite result="composite1" operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" in="flood"/>'+
         '<feGaussianBlur result="blur" stdDeviation="0.5" in="composite1"/>'+
         '<feOffset result="offset" dy="0" dx="0"/>'+
         '<feComposite result="composite2" operator="atop" in2="offset" in="offset"/>'+
        '</filter>'+
        '</svg>';
    dial.innerHTML = face;

    for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        var mrkrLength = (i % 5) ? 7.5 : 25;
        var mrkrWidth = (i % 5) ? 3 : 7.5;

        mrkrs[i] = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'line');
        with(mrkrs[i]) {
            setAttribute('x1', '100');
            setAttribute('y1', '0');
            setAttribute('x2', '100');
            setAttribute('y2', mrkrLength);
            setAttribute('stroke', markColour);
            setAttribute('stroke-width', mrkrWidth);
            setAttribute('stroke-linecap', 'butt');
            setAttribute("clip-path", "url(#dialPath)");
            setAttribute( "transform","rotate("+i * 6+", 100, 100)");
        }
        MobaTimeClock.appendChild(mrkrs[i]);
    }

    var logo = '<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 160 106" ' +
    'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">' +
    '<path d="M72.764.744C74.936.347 77.136 0 79.35.052c.94.017 1.88.01 2.82.08 4.8' +
    '35.364 9.615 1.48 14.098 3.357 4.685 1.99 9.022 4.85 12.635 8.467 3.488 3.46 6' +
    '.303 7.605 8.27 12.123 1.837 4.26 2.964 8.834 3.284 13.47.3 4.69-.077 9.427-1.' +
    '208 13.988-.398 1.737-.95 3.43-1.494 5.126-3.685-2.417-7.306-4.932-10.977-7.37' +
    '.638-2.657 1.03-5.388.955-8.128-.032-2.894-.504-5.78-1.35-8.545-1.36-4.383-3.75' +
    '-8.47-7.038-11.658-3.758-3.765-8.715-6.24-13.914-7.168-2.006-.367-4.047-.537-6' +
    '.083-.51-2.38.167-4.755.56-7.04 1.256-.07.018-.212.05-.282.067-4.875 1.52-9.37' +
    ' 4.36-12.692 8.292-3.532 4.122-5.726 9.365-6.367 14.77-.3 2.187-.26 4.41-.16 6' +
    '.61.152 1.61.355 3.218.707 4.797-3.644 2.364-7.266 4.76-10.93 7.09-1.812-4.79-' +
    '2.977-9.862-3.083-15.002-.237-8.587 2.43-17.226 7.466-24.152C51.114 11.27 56.7' +
    '94 6.69 63.212 3.79c3.06-1.366 6.266-2.402 9.552-3.046z" fill-opacity=".9" fill="'+markColour+'"/>' +
    '<path d="M48.772 76.595L55.83 71.9l1.774 1.816c1.023 1.047 2.286 2.145 2.984 2' +
    '.595 5.233 3.37 12.434 5.067 20.513 4.835 3.703-.106 5.01-.245 8.036-.856 2.72' +
    '-.55 5.2-1.387 7.582-2.557 2.47-1.213 4.22-2.505 5.976-4.41l1.357-1.47 7.045 4' +
    '.715 7.045 4.715 11.09.06c6.934.038 11.03.002 10.926-.096-.828-.782-35.83-26.7' +
    '53-35.916-26.648-4.85 5.9-8.918 9.252-13.73 11.313-3.472 1.487-6.387 2.055-10.' +
    '566 2.058-9.514.007-16.507-3.84-24.292-13.368-.08-.096-31.817 23.46-35.66 26.4' +
    '67-.395.308-.217.312 10.66.266l11.064-.047 7.056-4.695z" fill="url(#a)"/>' +
    '<path d="M81.42 90.82h-3.505l-5.58 15.26h3.473l1.078-2.32 5.597.02 1.08 2.302h' +
    '3.32l-5.462-15.26zm-1.717 4.213l1.667 5.944h-3.285l1.618-5.944zm-22.434-4.23h-' +
    '5.174v15.26l6.303.016c1.6.02 3.624-1.607 3.994-3.73.084-2.25-.845-4.16-2.376-4' +
    '.446.876-.41 1.45-1.89 1.348-3.854-.238-1.944-2.26-3.392-4.097-3.248m.976 3.73' +
    'c.353.662.153 1.337-.05 1.837-.656.768-1.837.714-2.78.714v-3.302c.842 0 2.308-' +
    '.16 2.83.75m.625 5.747c.37.606.286 1.73.103 2.16-.893.998-2.16.962-3.523.8v-3.' +
    '604c1.618-.108 2.46-.09 3.42.643M15.118 90.8l2.41 15.24-3 .037-1.432-8.89-3.75' +
    '8 8.89-.926-.037-3.675-8.496-1.517 8.532L0 106.042l2.36-15.277h3.17l3.166 8.744' +
    ' 3.42-8.708h3zm19.23 11.673c-2.29 0-4.18-2-4.18-4.427 0-2.427 1.89-4.425 4.18-' +
    '4.425 2.293 0 4.18 1.998 4.18 4.425 0 2.426-1.887 4.427-4.18 4.427m0 3.604c4.2' +
    '8 0 7.77-3.605 7.77-8.032 0-4.425-3.49-8.048-7.77-8.048-4.28 0-7.768 3.623-7.7' +
    '68 8.048 0 4.427 3.488 8.03 7.768 8.03M98.68 91.482h8.56l-.285 1.68h-3.49l-1.8' +
    '87 12.883h-1.754l1.924-12.884h-3.374l.306-1.68zm18.623 0h1.753l-2.19 14.563h-1' +
    '.738l2.175-14.562zm24.506-1.017l.756 15.58h-1.99l-.115-9.94-5.898 10.242-2.715' +
    '-10.242-3.166 9.94h-1.972l5.444-15.58 3 11.796 6.657-11.797zm18.236 1.018l-.43' +
    '8 1.68h-5.648l-.608 4.086h5.546l-.32 1.66h-5.494l-.876 5.46h5.798l-.286 1.677h' +
    '-7.55l2.174-14.562h7.702z" fill-opacity="1.0" fill="'+markColour+'"/>' + 
    '<defs>' +
    '<pattern xlink:href="#b" id="a" patternTransform="translate(364.52 610.068) scale(6.07904)"/>' +
    '<pattern id="b" patternTransform="scale(10)" height="1" width="1.07" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">' +
    '<path fill="'+markColour+'" d="M0 0h.5v1H0z"/>' + 
    '</pattern>' + 
    '</defs>' + 
    '</svg>';

    var mtl = d.createElement('div');
    mtl.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;'
        +'position: absolute;'
        +'height: '+xy(9)+'px;'
        +'top: '+xy(68)+'px;'
        +'paddingBottom: '+xy(1)+'px;'
        +'margin: auto; left: 0;right: 0;');
    mtl.innerHTML = logo;
    dial.appendChild(mtl);

    /* Generic container for all hands */

    var handContainers = 'display: block;'
        +'position: absolute;'
        +'height: '+xy(100)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(100)+'px;'
        +'font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px; padding: 0;'
        +'margin: auto; top: 0;bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;'
        +'transform-origin: center center;'

    /* Hour hand */

    var houClone = handContainers;
    var houContainer = d.createElement('div');
    houContainer.setAttribute('style', houClone);
    houContainer.style.zIndex = 50;
    dial.appendChild(houContainer);
    var houHand = d.createElement('div');
    var housvg = vb +
    '<polygon points="95,33 105,33 106,125 94,125" fill="'+handColour+'" stroke="none" "'+dum+'" />'+
    '</svg>';
    houHand.innerHTML = housvg;
    houContainer.appendChild(houHand);
    var houShad = houContainer.cloneNode(true);
    dial.appendChild(houShad);
    genShadKillClone(houShad,housvg, 0, 3);

    /* Minute hand */

    var minClone = handContainers;
    var minContainer = d.createElement('div');
    minContainer.setAttribute('style',minClone);
    minContainer.style.zIndex = 52;
    dial.appendChild(minContainer);
    var minHand = d.createElement('div');
    var minsvg =  vb +
    '<polygon points="96,5 104,5 105,125 95,125" fill="'+handColour+'" stroke="none" "'+dum+'" />'+
    '</svg>';
    minHand.innerHTML = minsvg;
    minContainer.appendChild(minHand);
    var minShad = minContainer.cloneNode(true);
    dial.appendChild(minShad);
    genShadKillClone(minShad,minsvg, 0, 4);

    /* Seconds hand */

    var secClone = handContainers;
    var secContainer = d.createElement('div');
    secContainer.setAttribute('style',secClone);
    secContainer.style.zIndex = 54;
    dial.appendChild(secContainer);
    var secHand = d.createElement('div');
    var secsvg =  vb +
    '<path d="M100 23.475a10 10 0 0 0-10 10 10 10 0 0 0 8.22 9.832V135h3.56V43.31a10 10 0 0 0 8.22-9.835 10 10 0 0 0-10-10z" fill="'+sechandColour+'" "'+dum+'" />'+
    '</svg>';
    secHand.innerHTML = secsvg;
    secContainer.appendChild(secHand);
    var secShad = secContainer.cloneNode(true);
    dial.appendChild(secShad);
    genShadKillClone(secShad,secsvg, 0, 5);

    /* Clock glass */

    var glass = d.createElement('div');
    glass.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;'
        +'position: absolute;'
        +'height: '+xy(112)+'px;'
        +'width: '+xy(112)+'px;'
        +'margin: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;right: 0;' 
        +'border-radius: '+clockShape+'%;'
        +'background-image: url("http://i61.tinypic.com/300xjcn.png");'
        +'background-size: cover;'
        +'opacity: 0.3;'
        +'z-index: 55;'
        +'overflow: hidden;');
    innerRim.appendChild(glass);

    function secKeyFrames() {
        var secSheet = (d.getElementById('tmpSecSheet'+idx));
        if (secSheet) {
            secSheet.parentNode.removeChild(secSheet);
        }
        secClone = handContainers;
        var p1 = secDeg;
        var p2 = secDeg+6;
        var p3 = secDeg+4;
        var p4 = secDeg+6;
        var p5 = secDeg+5; 
        var p6 = secDeg+6; 
        var secframes = '@keyframes s'+idx+'gen'+secIncr+' { '
        +'0% { transform: rotate('+p1+'deg) '+eiatf+';}'
        +'30% { transform: rotate('+p2+'deg) '+eoatf+';}'
        +'45% { transform: rotate('+p3+'deg) '+eiatf+';}'
        +'60% { transform: rotate('+p4+'deg) '+eoatf+';}' 
        +'70% { transform: rotate('+p5+'deg) '+eiatf+';}'
        +'80%,100% { transform: rotate('+p6+'deg) '+eoatf+';}}';  
        var ss = document.createElement( 'style' );
        ss.setAttribute('id', 'tmpSecSheet'+idx);
        ss.innerHTML = secframes;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(ss);
        var secAni = 'animation: s'+idx+'gen'+secIncr+' '+secSpan+' 1 forwards;';
        secClone += secAni;
        secHand.setAttribute('style', secClone);
        secHand.style.zIndex = 104;
        dial.appendChild(secHand);
        secShad.setAttribute('style', secClone);
        secShad.style.top = xy(5)+'px';
        secShad.style.left = xy(0)+'px';
    }

    function minKeyFrames() {
        var minSheet = (d.getElementById('tmpMinSheet'+idx));
        if (minSheet) {
            minSheet.parentNode.removeChild(minSheet);
        }
        minClone = handContainers;
        var p1 = minDeg;
        var p2 = minDeg+6;
        var p3 = minDeg+4;
        var p4 = minDeg+6;
        var p5 = minDeg+5; 
        var p6 = minDeg+6;
        var minframes = '@keyframes m'+idx+'gen'+minIncr+' { '
        +'0% { transform: rotate('+p1+'deg) '+eiatf+';}'
        +'30% { transform: rotate('+p2+'deg) '+eoatf+';}'
        +'45% { transform: rotate('+p3+'deg) '+eiatf+';}'
        +'60% { transform: rotate('+p4+'deg) '+eoatf+';}' 
        +'70% { transform: rotate('+p5+'deg) '+eiatf+';}'
        +'80%,100% { transform: rotate('+p6+'deg) '+eoatf+';}}';
        var ms = document.createElement( 'style' );
        ms.setAttribute('id', 'tmpMinSheet'+idx);
        ms.innerHTML = minframes;
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(ms);
        var minAni = 'animation: m'+idx+'gen'+minIncr+' '+minSpan+' 1 forwards;';
        minClone += minAni;
        minHand.setAttribute('style', minClone);
        minHand.style.zIndex = 102;
        dial.appendChild(minHand);
        minShad.setAttribute('style', minClone);
        minShad.style.top = xy(4)+'px';
        minShad.style.left = xy(0)+'px';
    }

    function houKeyFrames() {
        var houSheet = (d.getElementById('tmphouSheet'+idx));
        if (houSheet) {
            houSheet.parentNode.removeChild(houSheet);
        }
        houClone = handContainers;
        var p1 = houDeg;
        var p2 = houDeg+1;
        var p3 = houDeg+0.4;
        var p4 = houDeg+1;
        var p5 = houDeg+0.5; 
        var p6 = houDeg+1; 
        var houframes = '@keyframes h'+idx+'gen'+houIncr+' { '
        +'0% { transform: rotate('+p1+'deg) '+eiatf+';}'
        +'30% { transform: rotate('+p2+'deg) '+eoatf+';}'
        +'45% { transform: rotate('+p3+'deg) '+eiatf+';}'
        +'60% { transform: rotate('+p4+'deg) '+eoatf+';}' 
        +'70% { transform: rotate('+p5+'deg) '+eiatf+';}'
        +'80%,100% { transform: rotate('+p6+'deg) '+eoatf+';}}';
        var hs = document.createElement( 'style' );
        hs.setAttribute('id', 'tmphouSheet'+idx);
        hs.innerHTML = houframes;
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(hs);
        var houAni = 'animation: h'+idx+'gen'+houIncr+' '+houSpan+' 1 forwards;';
        houClone += houAni;
        houHand.setAttribute('style', houClone);
        houHand.style.zIndex = 100;
        dial.appendChild(houHand);
        houShad.setAttribute('style', houClone);
        houShad.style.top = xy(3)+'px';
        houShad.style.left = xy(0)+'px';
     }

    function mobaSeconds() {
        mobasec++;
        secIncr++;
        secDeg = (mobasec-1) * 6;
        secHand.removeAttribute('style');
        secKeyFrames();
        if (secIncr > 59) {
            secIncr = 0;
        }
        mobaTimer = setTimeout(mobaSeconds, mobacycle);
        if (mobasec > 59) {
            clearTimeout(mobaTimer);
            mobasec = 0;
            firstrun = false;
        }
    }

    function clock() {
        var x = new Date();
        var seconds = x.getSeconds();
        var minutes = x.getMinutes();
        var hours = (x.getHours() * 30) + (x.getMinutes() / 2);

        if (seconds !== preSec) {
            mobacycle -= mobaoffset;
            if (!firstrun && seconds == 1) {
                mobaSeconds();
            }
        }

        if (minutes !== preMin) {
            if (firstrun) {
                mobaSeconds();
            }
            if (!firstrun) {
                mobacycle = 1000-mobaoffset;
            }
            minIncr++;
            minDeg = (minutes-1) * 6;
            minHand.removeAttribute('style');
            minKeyFrames();
            if (minIncr > 59) {
                minIncr = 0;
            }
        }

        if (hours !== preHou) {
            houIncr++;
            houDeg = (hours-1) * 1;
            houHand.removeAttribute('style');
            houKeyFrames();
            if (houIncr > 59) {
                houIncr = 0;
            }
        }

        preSec = seconds;
        preMin = minutes;
        preHou = hours;

        tmr = setTimeout(clock, mls);
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', clock, false);
})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hilfiker/MobaTime Swiss Railway Clock</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: rgb(205,179,139);
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```